# Your connection is not private firebase hosting when removing www from url

Tags: firebase, redirect, dns, firebase-hosting

I'm using firebase hosting to host my website and so far it's great with this small exception that I don't know how to fix:

If you go to mywebsite https://www.morningharwood.com my website works.

If you go to http://www.morningharwood.com my website work.

If you go to only [morningharwood.com](http://morningharwood.com) it works.

If you go to [www.morningharwood.com](http://www.morningharwood.com) it will work.

However, if you remove the www the website throws an error `Your connection is not private`.

### **Question:**

What is the proper implementation to afford the opportunity for any url combination to work e.g. http://morningharwood.com, https://morningharwood.com

My only solution is to add a redirect? but I don't htink this will work.
[image]

Comment: Hmmm ... I have not tried it myself but yes I'm not sure redirect would do the trick either. Sorry but am curious to see the answer as I am getting there myself. Cheers

Comment: I saw another video where the guy didn't default the domain to www.  Maybe thats the preferred way that could work?

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry I'm not sure. I am yet to get there, fingers crossed soon. Did you have any problem connecting your domain? I am about to purchase a domain, any recommendation as to where I can find a good provider?

Comment: domains.google.com  is great hosting.  Integration are fabulous too as it's owned by Google.  Support is great too

Comment: For me, regardless of which of the above links I click, I get redirected to `https://www.morningharwood.com`, so it looks like the redirect is working correctly.

Comment: @Grimthorr looks like the redirect finally.

Comment: Adding a redirect does take a while to propagate (it stays on `pending` status until ready), but I think a redirect is your best course of action here. I'll add as an answer if this helps?

Comment: Go for it. is this standard practice? will this redirect cause another http request? like if I was to remove the www off the connected custom domain would I still need the redirect?  or is it best practice to keep the www if so why?

Comment: It's really down to personal preference whether you keep or drop the `www` but it's good practice to have one redirect or point to the other either way, so that users who type either will reach the correct website. It may make another HTTP request but the impact would be negligible and redirects like this are common practice. The other option would be to setup your domain's DNS to redirect the base domain to `www` using a CNAME record or similar.

Comment: Any downfall to SEO when redirecting between the two? Sorry to beat this to death.  Also plop an answer down if you want those sweeet sweet points

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, thanks and glad to see you found a solution

Comment: I'm not aware of SEO downfalls with redirecting one to the other, if anything it ensures the website is indexed and linked to with your preferred choice and could avoid duplicates (although most search engines are clever so that's likely a non-issue). If it's any consolation: I always redirect one to the other as a way to ensure all visitors are using the same access point, but again it's mostly personal preference I'd say. The `www` prefix is actually superfluous nowadays though and is a throwback to "the good old days" when it completed the URL, but subdomains have done away with the need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have suggested, using a redirect to point all users of the base domain to the `www` variant should work, and Firebase will automatically redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

After creating a redirect in the console, it can take a while to propagate and will show status of `pending` until it's ready. You can also [redirect or rewrite Firebase Hosting traffic using the `firebase.json` file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-redirects).

It's really down to personal (or client) preference whether you keep or drop the `www` but it's good practice to have one redirect or point to the other so that users who type either will reach the correct website.

The other option would be to setup your domain's DNS to redirect the base domain to `www` using a CNAME record or similar.